# Calculating Confidence Interval for a Proportion Py(Spark)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, statistics, confidence-interval

I am calculating proportions of gender in pyspark using the following function.

In addition to this, I also want to calculate a confidence interval for a proportion as this in python e.g [Calculating Confidence Interval for a Proportion in One Sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51794473/calculating-confidence-interval-for-a-proportion-in-one-sample)

So I should have one/two extra columns with  lower_ci & upper_ci

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
def gender_prop(df, grp):
    test_df = df.filter( 
        F.col('GENDER').isin(['0','F'])
        ).groupBy(grp).agg(
            F.mean(
                F.when(F.col('GENDER') == F.lit('M'), 1.0).otherwise(0.0)
            ).alias('gender_score'),
            F.count(F.lit(1)).alias('total')
        ).filter('no_of_streams > 100')
    return test_df

 df = gender_prop(df, 'title')
 display(df)
 title   gender_prop            total
1 ABC    0.2749954192878519     491190
2 CART   0.5417543859649123     320625
3 NUMB   0.3385603833169988     275490
4 PRO    0.24459397661200757    229605
5 SHOW   0.2673127254721652     212055
```

Sorry for being vague, so basically I want to do exactly something in pyspark as this example

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math

df=pd.DataFrame({'Class': ['A1','A1','A1','A2','A3','A3'], 
                 'Force': [50,150,100,120,140,160] },
                 columns=['Class', 'Force'])
print(df)
print('-'*30)

stats = df.groupby(['Class'])['Force'].agg(['mean', 'count', 'std'])
print(stats)
print('-'*30)

ci95_hi = []
ci95_lo = []

for i in stats.index:
    m, c, s = stats.loc[i]
    ci95_hi.append(m + 1.96*s/math.sqrt(c))
    ci95_lo.append(m - 1.96*s/math.sqrt(c))

stats['ci95_hi'] = ci95_hi
stats['ci95_lo'] = ci95_lo
print(stats)
```

I would appreciate your help
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first code snippet has many unclear filters, but here's the idea:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
def gender_prop(df, grp):
    col = F.when(F.col('GENDER') == F.lit('M'), 1.0).otherwise(0.0)

    return df.groupBy(grp).agg(
        F.mean(col).alias('avg'),
        F.count(F.lit(1)).alias('total'),
        F.stddev(col).alias('std')
    ).withColumn(
        'ci95_hi',
        F.col('avg') + 1.96 * F.col('std') / F.sqrt(F.col('total'))
    ).withColumn(
        'ci95_lo',
        F.col('avg') - 1.96 * F.col('std') / F.sqrt(F.col('total'))
    )
```